# Can I remove the first two git commits?

Tags: git

I'm doing some analytical works on the author-contribution data on a git repository. I extract the contribution of each contributor on each method. I found out one contributor has oddly more contribution than others, and I found out that's because before creating this git repo, they were using another repository and they just copy-pasted the whole project to the new repo(so lots of new files were added in the second commit, the first commit is just adding .gitignore). Since that person added all the files in the second commit, he is contributing significantly more than other contributors. I want to somehow delete/ignore this commit to see the contribution data excluding this commit. Is there anyway to do so?

I tried to use git cherry-pick from third commit to the last one but It failed since the added files in second commit changed in next commits.

Comment: What's the error you got when cherry picking?

Comment: The solution is probably not modifying the repository, but adjusting your analytical software to ignore that particular commit.

Comment: You could rewrite history so that it begins two commits later. But then everything would be attributed to the author of that new first commit. You need to change your evaluation method, not the Git history.

Comment: If you want to do inventory on all warehouses except two of them the way to do that is not to blow up the two warehouses that you want to ignore.

Comment: Something in your methodology seems off if a contribution which touches more than one file counts as multiple contributions, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to simply ignore/delete these files as other contributors made changes to them in later commits and you don't want to lose their contribution in your calculations.

It seems your end goal is to find the amount of contributions done by each individual contributor, but you want to exclude the contribution done by `ABC` author specifically in the second commit in the history. If I understand it correctly then here is the solution:

1. $ git checkout <second_commit_id>
2. $ git checkout -b temp-branch (i.e. create new branch from second commit)
3. Now find the amount of contributions done by `ABC` by running whatever logic you have.
4. Go back to your original branch.
5. Calculate contributions done by each contributor using same logic.
6. But for `ABC` contributor subtract the amount of contributions you calculated in step #3.

Git tracks each addition / deletion  /update of files and credits for that change to contributor / committer. In the above mentioned steps we are specifically subtracting `ABC's` contributions that he did in the second commit. Now in subsequent commits even if any other contributor or rather `ABC` made changes to the files introduced in the second commit then those contributions will still be considered in the above process / calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can locally replace the wonky commit with a replacement commit authored by "Initial Commit <initial@example.com>",

```
wonkycommit=$(git rev-parse that-second-to-last-commit)
replacement=$(
        git cat-file -p $wonkycommit \
        | sed '1,/^$/ s/ .*>/ Initial Commit <initial@example.com>/' \
        | git hash-object -wt commit --stdin
)
git replace $wonkycommit $replacement
```

then `git replace -d` the entry when you're done (or do stuff like this in scratch-monkey clones, `` git clone --bare -s --no-tags . `mktemp -d`; cd $_ `` is *dirt* cheap, like, laughably so).